# SQL Server XML: efficient parsing of EAV style xml to multiple columns based on values

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, entity-attribute-value

I have XML which lists attributes in an EAV style of the form:

```
<record>
  <ref>1</ref>
  <attributes>
    <attr>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
      <Value>x1</Value>
    </attr>
    <attr>
      <Name>Name2</Name>
      <Value>x2</Value>      
    </attr>
    ...
  </attribtues>
</record>
<record>
  <ref>2</ref>
  <attributes>
    <attr>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
      <Value>y1</Value>
    </attr>
    <attr>
      <Name>Name3</Name>
      <Value>y3</Value>      
    </attr>
    ...
  </attribtues>
</record>
...
```

and I want to manipulate this in SQL Server into a table, more of the sparse-columns style: (the column names must be dependent on the values of the name field, but are from a set of known columns)

```
Record | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | ...
1      | x1    | x2    | null  | ...
2      | y1    | null  | y3    | ...
...
```

I can use T-SQL XML manipulation to create an EAV table then convert this to the table above using a left join on the xml for every column, but this seems a very inefficient way. (I also cannot use pivot due to the compatibility setting on the server.)

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a while into manipulating the XML so that the Name value pairs were replaced with one tag, but it looks like the xml operations in sql will not update many tags in one query. I tried string replacements, but this will get very slow with large xml.

In the end I used the following, but I am not happy about it:

the xml to be parsed:

```
declare @thexml xml = 
'<root>
<record>
  <ref>1</ref>
  <attributes>
    <attr>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
      <Value>x1</Value>
    </attr>
    <attr>
      <Name>Name2</Name>
      <Value>x2</Value>      
    </attr>
  </attributes>
</record>
<record>
  <ref>2</ref>
  <attributes>
    <attr>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
      <Value>y1</Value>
    </attr>
    <attr>
      <Name>Name3</Name>
      <Value>y3</Value>      
    </attr>
  </attributes>
</record>
</root>'
```

I generate a table defining the allowed attributes here, but in the actual implementation this is a mapping table between the column names and the Name values in the tags. It's not really part of the solution.

```
declare @sqlcmd varchar(max) = ''
create table ColNames (ColName varchar(50))

insert into ColNames
select distinct record.attr.value('(./Name)[1]','varchar(50)')
from @thexml.nodes('/root/record/attributes/attr') as record(attr)

select @sqlcmd = coalesce(@sqlcmd + ', ' + ColName + ' varchar(50)', ColName)
from ColNames
set @sqlcmd = 'create table Output (ref varchar(50)' + @sqlcmd + ')'

EXEC (@sqlcmd)
```

then I fill in the references to keep all the attribute updates separate from the row inserts:

```
insert into Output (ref)
select distinct record.attr.value('(./ref)[1]','varchar(50)')
from @thexml.nodes('/root/record') as record(attr)
```

I get the EAV table in the fashion described in the Question:

```
create table EAVAttributes (ref varchar(50), Name varchar(50), Value varchar(50))

insert into EAVAttributes
select 
root.records.value('(./ref)[1]','varchar(50)'), 
record.attr.value('(./Name)[1]','varchar(50)'), 
record.attr.value('(./Value)[1]','varchar(50)')
from @thexml.nodes('/root/record') as root(records)
cross apply root.records.nodes('./attributes/attr') as record(attr)
```

... And call dynamic sql to fill in the attributes. I concatenate them to avoid using a cursor, but I probably should just use a cursor.

```
set @sqlcmd = ''
select @sqlcmd = coalesce(@sqlcmd +
                          'Update o set ' + ColName + '= eav.Value ' + 
                          'from EAVAttributes eav ' +
                          'inner join Output o ' +
                          'on eav.ref = o.ref ' +
                          'and eav.Name = '''+ColName+'''; ', ColName)
from ColNames

EXEC (@sqlcmd)

select * from Output
```

There must be a better way to do this! :(